# Check for positive value - constraint in gurobi python

Tags: python, gurobi

I want to write a constraint for doing this

```
if A > 0 then B = 1 else B = 0
```

where A is a decision variable. B is a binary decision variable. What is the most efficient (if there is, for memory and CPU usage) way for doing this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indicator constraints are simple:

```
 B=1 => A >= 0.001
 B=0 => A <= 0
```

Use good bounds on A to help Gurobi.

If you have good bounds, you can also do directly:

```
 A <= B * U
 A >= L * (1-B) +  B * 0.001 
 L <= A <= U
```

Comment: m.addConstrs(y[i,k,j,jp] <= (100000*y_bin[i,k,j,jp]) for i,k in userpair for j,jp in arcs);m.addConstrs(y[i,k,j,jp] >= (y_bin[i,k,j,jp]) for i,k in userpair for j,jp in arcs); Apparently userpair has 2500 indexes and arcs has 2500 indexes too. First of all, that looks like what you advise right? And that constraint adding step takes a lot of time and it consumes lots of memory as I observe. Is that normal? By the way I did not define any U and L bounds for y, but I know the bounds. Does it change anything if I define or not?

Comment: and why do you insert 0.001 as a bias and not 0 directly? Thank you.

Comment: You asked for A>0.

Comment: Oh yes. That is right. But sometimes I see people define a very small epsilon value like 10e-6. Does it change or improve the computation time/efficiency? Sorry if the question is silly.

Comment: Well there are feasibility tolerances, and scaling.